Can't set frequency more than 48MHz on STM32F767ZI
I configure the RCC for 48 MHz as follows:
    rcc.cr.modify(|_, w| w.hseon().on());
    while rcc.cr.read().hserdy().is_not_ready() {}
    println!("{:b}", rcc.cr.read().bits());
    println!("Hse ready");

    rcc.pllcfgr.modify(|_, w| w.pllsrc().hse());
    rcc.pllcfgr.modify(unsafe {|_, w| w.pllm().bits(4)});
    rcc.pllcfgr.modify(unsafe {|_, w| w.plln().bits(96)});
    rcc.pllcfgr.modify(|_, w| w.pllp().div4());

    rcc.cr.modify(|_, w| w.pllon().on());
    while rcc.cr.read().pllrdy().is_not_ready() {}
    println!("Pll ready");

    rcc.cfgr.modify(|_, w| w.sw().pll());
    while !rcc.cfgr.read().sws().is_pll() {}
    println!("pll selectected");

and it is working.
If I configure the RCC to 54 MHz as follows:
    rcc.cr.modify(|_, w| w.hseon().on());
    while rcc.cr.read().hserdy().is_not_ready() {}
    println!("{:b}", rcc.cr.read().bits());
    println!("Hse ready");

    rcc.pllcfgr.modify(|_, w| w.pllsrc().hse());
    rcc.pllcfgr.modify(unsafe {|_, w| w.pllm().bits(4)});
    rcc.pllcfgr.modify(unsafe {|_, w| w.plln().bits(108)});
    rcc.pllcfgr.modify(|_, w| w.pllp().div4());

    rcc.cr.modify(|_, w| w.pllon().on());
    while rcc.cr.read().pllrdy().is_not_ready() {}
    println!("Pll ready");

    rcc.cfgr.modify(|_, w| w.sw().pll());
    while !rcc.cfgr.read().sws().is_pll() {}
    println!("pll selectected");

I get this error:
ERROR probe_rs::architecture::arm::core::armv7m: The core is in locked up status as a result of an unrecoverable exception
Error: Failed to attach to RTT

Caused by:
    RTT Initialized correctly, but there were no active channels configured

I have tried setting the prescaler ABP1 to DIV2, but it doesn't help me.
How can I solve this problem?

Your numbers look fine (assuming an 8MHz HSE), however I might not expect printf to carry on working while you change the clock speed!  Can you try flashing an LED instead?

Read about the latency parameter in the FLASH_ACR register and set it appropriately.

@kkrambo thanks, your comment helped me solve this problem

48MHz is usually the magic limit from where on you need to configure flash wait states on many MCUs (At least ST och Microchip ARM parts both have this limit, might be others too). Perhaps that's called "ACR" on this particular part.

I set the FLASH_ACR register appropriately and the problem was solved:
    rcc.cr.modify(|_, w| w.hseon().on());
    while rcc.cr.read().hserdy().is_not_ready() {}
    println!("Hse ready");

    rcc.pllcfgr.modify(|_, w| w.pllsrc().hse());
    rcc.pllcfgr.modify(unsafe {|_, w| w.pllm().bits(4)});
    rcc.pllcfgr.modify(unsafe {|_, w| w.plln().bits(108)});
    rcc.pllcfgr.modify(|_, w| w.pllp().div2());

    rcc.cr.modify(|_, w| w.pllon().on());
    while rcc.cr.read().pllrdy().is_not_ready() {}
    println!("Pll ready");

    dp.FLASH.acr.modify(|_, w| w.latency().ws9());
    while !dp.FLASH.acr.read().latency().is_ws9() {}

    rcc.cfgr.modify(|_, w| w
        .ppre1().div2()
        .ppre2().div2()
    );

    rcc.cfgr.modify(|_, w| w.sw().pll());
    while !rcc.cfgr.read().sws().is_pll() {}
    println!("pll selectected");

